# How do I successfully enable the diagnostic settings of windows virtual machine using Rest API?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-sdk

**Enable diagnostic by Azure REST API:**

I'm using the Azure REST API to enable diagnostic. Below is the request that I send to Azure.

**Method:** PUT

**HEADERS:**

Authorization:Bearer {Access_token}

Content-Type:application/json

**Request URI:**

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{VMName}/extensions/IaaSDiagnostics?api-version=2016-04-30-preview
```

**Request Body:**

```
const reqBody = {
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8cxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/param/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/parwin/extensions/IaaSDiagnostics",
            "name": "IaaSDiagnostics",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "location": "eastus",
            "properties": {
                "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics",
                "type": "IaaSDiagnostics",
                "typeHandlerVersion": "1.5",
                "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                "settings": {
                    "StorageAccount": "paramstorage10",
                    "WadCfg": base64.encode('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><PublicConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration"><WadCfg><DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="5120"><PerformanceCounters scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M"><PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" sampleRate="PT1M" unit="percent"><annotation displayName="Processor - total processor time" locale="en-us"/></PerformanceCounterConfiguration></PerformanceCounters><WindowsEventLog scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M"><DataSource name="System!*"/></WindowsEventLog><Metrics resourceId="/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8cxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/param/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/parwin"><MetricAggregation scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1H"/><MetricAggregation scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M"/></Metrics></DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration></WadCfg></PublicConfig>')
                }
            }
        };
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "name": "IaaSDiagnostics",
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8cxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/param/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/parwin/extensions/IaaSDiagnostics",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
  "location": "eastus",
  "properties": {
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "provisioningState": "Creating",
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics",
    "type": "IaaSDiagnostics",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.5",
    "settings": {
      "StorageAccount": "paramstorage10",
      "WadCfg": "GFDHasdsdfnkmsdfknsdifdskfsdkisf87s8443nkj4ejfgdf487843503603 vkngsfkkfgkjsfnvkjfdsnisfgsnfsgjksfigfsgnskfdgjsfgksfngsfgkslskakfdabvdbd674435bq4jZmM5Y2UyOTUtYjdmYS00MGZiLTgzNTMtOGM2M2RjNTI0NjRjL3Jlc291cmNlR3JvdXBzL3BhcmFtMDgxMi9wcm92aWRlcnMvTWljcm9zb2Z0LkNvbXB1dGUvdmlydHVhbE1hY2hpbmVzL3BhcndpbiI+PE1ldHJpY0FnZ3JlZ2F0aW9uIHNjaGVkdWxlZFRyYW5zZmVyUGVyaW9kPSJQVDFIIi8+PE1ldHJpY0FnZ3JlZ2F0aW9uIHNjaGVkdWxlZFRyYW5zZmVyUGVyaW9kPSJQVDFNIi8+PC9NZXRyaWNzPjwvRGlhZ25vc3RpY01vbml0b3JDb25maWd1cmF0aW9uPjwvV2FkQ2ZnPjdskfjgsdfgksfgk849349f=="
    }
  }
}
```

**AZURE UI:**

[image]

[image]

**Issue:**

After Request, I'm getting the successful response but When I'm going to Azure then the Diagnostics extension don't have successfully installed.

**So how do I successfully install the diagnostics setting extension ??**

Comment: Please connect to your VM and check the file in `C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics<DiagnosticsVersion>\`. It is a log file. You can get detailed error message.

Comment: Hello Jim, Thank you for your response. I'm providing error log at below:

Comment: **[12/16/2020 05:44:56.85] Executing: C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics\1.18.0.4\DiagnosticsPluginLauncher.exe 
[12/16/2020 05:45:01.08] Execution Complete.
######
Execution Output:


Execution Error:
Could not extract thumbprint from JSON config file
Failed to read configuration.

######
 Number of Tries:
 1Command C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics\1.18.0.4\DiagnosticsPluginLauncher.exe of Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics has exited with Exit code: -3**

Comment: Can you please help, where I'm doing mistake in my JSON data..

Answer (score 1):

Now Windows Azure Diagnostics extension configuration accepts the JSON formate. So we can define the configuration as JSON Object. Regrading how to define it, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostics-extension-schema-windows#isenabled-element) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostics-extension-windows-install#powershell-deployment)

For example

**URL**

```
 https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}/extensions/IaaSDiagnostics?api-version=2020-06-01
```

Body

```
{
    "location": "",
    "settings": {
        "StorageAccount": "<storage account name>",
        "WadCfg": {
            "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
                "overallQuotaInMB": 5120,
                "Metrics": {
                    "resourceId": "<the resource id of your vm>",
                    "MetricAggregation": [{
                            "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1H"
                        }, {
                            "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs": {
                    "scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter": "Error"
                },
                "PerformanceCounters": {
                    "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
                    "PerformanceCounterConfiguration": [{
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Processor Information(_Total)\\% Processor Time",
                            "unit": "Percent",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Processor Information(_Total)\\% Privileged Time",
                            "unit": "Percent",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Processor Information(_Total)\\% User Time",
                            "unit": "Percent",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Processor Information(_Total)\\Processor Frequency",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\System\\Processes",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Process(_Total)\\Thread Count",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Process(_Total)\\Handle Count",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\System\\System Up Time",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\System\\Context Switches/sec",
                            "unit": "CountPerSecond",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\System\\Processor Queue Length",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\% Committed Bytes In Use",
                            "unit": "Percent",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Available Bytes",
                            "unit": "Bytes",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Committed Bytes",
                            "unit": "Bytes",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Cache Bytes",
                            "unit": "Bytes",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Pool Paged Bytes",
                            "unit": "Bytes",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Pool Nonpaged Bytes",
                            "unit": "Bytes",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Pages/sec",
                            "unit": "CountPerSecond",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Page Faults/sec",
                            "unit": "CountPerSecond",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Process(_Total)\\Working Set",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Process(_Total)\\Working Set - Private",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Disk Time",
                            "unit": "Percent",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Disk Read Time",
                            "unit": "Percent",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Disk Write Time",
                            "unit": "Percent",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Idle Time",
                            "unit": "Percent",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Bytes/sec",
                            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Read Bytes/sec",
                            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Write Bytes/sec",
                            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Transfers/sec",
                            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Reads/sec",
                            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Writes/sec",
                            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk sec/Transfer",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk sec/Read",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk sec/Write",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk Queue Length",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk Read Queue Length",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk Write Queue Length",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Free Space",
                            "unit": "Percent",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Free Megabytes",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Bytes Total/sec",
                            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Bytes Sent/sec",
                            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Bytes Received/sec",
                            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Packets/sec",
                            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Packets Sent/sec",
                            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Packets Received/sec",
                            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Packets Outbound Errors",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }, {
                            "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Packets Received Errors",
                            "unit": "Count",
                            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "WindowsEventLog": {
                    "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
                    "DataSource": [{
                            "name": "Application!*[System[(Level = 1 or Level = 2 or Level = 3)]]"
                        }, {
                            "name": "Security!*[System[band(Keywords,4503599627370496)]]"
                        }, {
                            "name": "System!*[System[(Level = 1 or Level = 2 or Level = 3)]]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "protectedSettings": {
        "storageAccountName": "<storage account name>",
        "storageAccountKey": "<storage account key>",
        "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net/"
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]